# Problem with properly coding XSLT stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm fairly new to XSLT but I think I have the basics down. However I've been going over the issue below for some time now and I cannot seem to find a working solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my (simplified) source XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<domain_objects>
    <gateway id='8b33703f411e4fbba99884225a35d11c'>
        <created_date>2018-10-30T12:51:41.555+01:00</created_date>
        <modified_date>2019-09-16T20:06:09.570+02:00</modified_date>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <vendor_name>Plugwise</vendor_name>
        <vendor_model>smile_open_therm</vendor_model>
        <hardware_version>AME Smile 2.0 board</hardware_version>
        <firmware_version>2.3.34</firmware_version>
        <lan_ip></lan_ip>
        <wifi_ip>10.72.0.50</wifi_ip>
        <time>2019-09-16T20:07:35+02:00</time>
        <timezone>Europe/Amsterdam</timezone>
        <ssh_relay>disabled</ssh_relay>
        <project id='b44f8eec07da4eb18deca4f79ecadadf'>
            <name>Robbshop.nl</name>
            <description/>
            <is_default>false</is_default>
            <visible_in_production>false</visible_in_production>
            <deleted_date></deleted_date>
            <modified_date>2018-11-25T09:36:05.068+01:00</modified_date>
            <created_date>2018-10-30T19:02:01+01:00</created_date>
        </project>
        <gateway_environment id='1aa4c520fa504fb79ea970da11bd6213'>
            <savings_result_value/>
            <thermostat_model/>
            <country>NL</country>
            <electricity_consumption_tariff_structure/>
            <electricity_production_peak_tariff/>
            <central_heating_model/>
            <household_children>0</household_children>
            <thermostat_brand/>
            <electricity_production_off_peak_tariff/>
            <central_heating_installation_date/>
            <electricity_consumption_off_peak_tariff/>
            <gas_consumption_tariff/>
            <modified_date>2018-11-25T10:54:27.350+01:00</modified_date>
            <electricity_production_tariff_structure/>
            <housing_construction_period>unknown</housing_construction_period>
            <housing_type>apartment</housing_type>
            <currency>EUR</currency>
            <savings_result_unit/>
            <household_adults>0</household_adults>
            <central_heating_year_of_manufacture/>
            <deleted_date></deleted_date>
            <modified_date>2018-11-25T10:54:27.350+01:00</modified_date>
            <created_date>2019-09-15T13:47:11+02:00</created_date>
        </gateway_environment>
        <features>
            <remote_control id='746aefbab30a42bcaebe0591c6acda6e'>
                <activation_date>2018-09-04T10:24:20+02:00</activation_date>
                <validity_period/>
                <valid_to></valid_to>
                <valid_from></valid_from>
                <grace_period/>
                <deleted_date></deleted_date>
                <modified_date>2018-11-25T09:36:05.134+01:00</modified_date>
                <created_date>2018-09-04T10:24:20+02:00</created_date>
            </remote_control>
        </features>
    </gateway>
</domain_objects>
```

What I'm trying to do is to get only the first 'gateway' node and all of it's children in the resulting XML document. In this example there only is 1 'gateway' node beneath the 'domain_objects' node, but there could me multiple gateway nodes in another source document.

In addition I want all attributes (from the first 'gateway' node and all it's children) to be converted to elements. For example:

```
<remote_control id='746aefbab30a42bcaebe0591c6acda6e'>
....
</remote_control>
```

should become

```
<remote_control>
   <id>746aefbab30a42bcaebe0591c6acda6e</id>
....
</remote_control>
```

The XSLT that I currently have almost works but only converts the 'id' attribute of the 'gateway' node itself to an element but none of it's child elements attributes get converted.

This is what I have right now:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <!-- don't output anything now, but keep processing children -->
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- modified identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="/domain_objects/gateway[1]">
        <!-- <xsl:copy-of select="self::node()"/> -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="gateway"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- attributes to elements -->
    <xsl:template match="@*" mode="gateway">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="gateway">
        <xsl:copy-of select="self::node()"/>      
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- avoid mixed content -->
    <xsl:template match="text()[../@*]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This results in:

```
<gateway>
   <id>8b33703f411e4fbba99884225a35d11c</id>
   <created_date>2018-10-30T12:51:41.555+01:00</created_date>
   ...
   <project id="b44f8eec07da4eb18deca4f79ecadadf">
      <name>Robbshop.nl</name>
      ....
   </project>
   ...
   <features>
      <remote_control id="746aefbab30a42bcaebe0591c6acda6e">
         <activation_date>2018-09-04T10:24:20+02:00</activation_date>
         <validity_period/>
         <valid_to/>
         <valid_from/>
         <grace_period/>
         <deleted_date/>
         <modified_date>2018-11-25T09:36:05.134+01:00</modified_date>
         <created_date>2018-09-04T10:24:20+02:00</created_date>
      </remote_control>
   </features>
   ...
</gateway>
```

As you can see the 'remote_control' and 'project' node still have their 'id' attribute. My XSLT does properly convert the main 'gateway' node attribute 'id' to an element, but it should also do this for all it's child nodes. I'm sure I'm overlooking something really simple but I would really appreciate some help in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is the template matching "*"

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="gateway">
    <xsl:copy-of select="self::node()"/>      
</xsl:template>
```

By using `xsl:copy-of` you copy-of, you are copying the element unchanged, and no other templates get applied. What you need to do is this to allow other templates to be used.

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="gateway">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="gateway"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Having said that, you could consider refactoring you XSLT stylesheet. Instead of thinking of what you need to copy, think of what you don't need to copy.

Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- attributes to elements -->
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>        
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- modified identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="domain_objects/gateway[position() > 1]" />

    <!-- avoid mixed content -->
    <xsl:template match="text()[../@*]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: In answer to your comment, if you don't want `domain_objects` in your XML, but do want to process its children, just add this template

```
<xsl:template match="domain_objects">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Alternatively, you could include the logic for selecting only the first gateway here too:

```
<xsl:template match="domain_objects">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="gateway[1]" />
</xsl:template>
```

Then you wouldn't need the other template that removed the other `gateway` elements, as they would no longer be selected in the first place:

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your first suggestion works like a charm - the second one is nice too, except it still leaves me with the 'domain_objects' root node that I want to get rid of. What would be the best way of doing that? Thanks again!

Comment: Excellent! Thanks again! You helped me understand XSLT a bit better than I did before.